# Questions about Firebase Security (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Ok. I am unsure about a few things with Firebase and its security and I was hoping that you guys would help me clear a few things up and also this might be a great topic to get some noob questions cleared up.

**1. Does FIRAuth.auth() manage tokens and connections?**

I have very simple code in my project:

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
   // Do Stuff
}
```

Is this all I need to do? How does this connect to Firebase? By this I mean is this data sent via GET/POST or is it encrypted? Should I be generating tokens and authentication and then checking that?

**2. Is this sufficient rules to stop access to the DB?**

I have defined some rules in my database:

```
 {
  "rules": {
   ".read": "auth != null",
   ".write": "auth != null",
    "score": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve here is the ability to save a score value in the DB. However, the database should only be accessible to the user logged in and also the entry with the `user_id` also. They should not be able to access another players score.

**3. Can I test these rules?**

Is there a way to have dummy users and privileges in the console so I can test these? If so, how?

**4. Is it possible to have SQL injections if there is no SQL database?**

Are there other methods I should be trying to stop, for example stopping MITM attack, etc.?

Appreciate all answers.

Comment: There are four questions here, some of them quite unrelated. Please post a single question per post.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen would you be available for chat?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859283/swift-firebase-security-not-working